# How can I tell the axes of a StackedBarChart to behave?

Tags: java, graphics, charts, javafx, javafx-8

Here is the situation:

[image]

The graph is initialized as such:

```
protected NumberAxis xAxis;
protected NumberAxis yAxis;
protected StackedAreaChart<Number, Number> chart;

protected final XYChart.Series<Number, Number> waitingSeries
    = new XYChart.Series<>();
protected final XYChart.Series<Number, Number> startedSeries
    = new XYChart.Series<>();
protected final XYChart.Series<Number, Number> successSeries
    = new XYChart.Series<>();
protected final XYChart.Series<Number, Number> failureSeries
    = new XYChart.Series<>();

// ...

@Override
public void init()
{
    // ...

    xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    xAxis.setLabel("Line number");
    xAxis.setForceZeroInRange(false);
    xAxis.setTickUnit(1.0);
    xAxis.setTickMarkVisible(false);

    yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    yAxis.setTickMarkVisible(false);

    chart = new StackedAreaChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);

    chart.setAnimated(false);
    chart.setTitle("Matcher status by line");

    waitingSeries.setName("Waiting for children");
    startedSeries.setName("Started this line");
    successSeries.setName("Succeeded this line");
    failureSeries.setName("Failed this line");

    final ObservableList<XYChart.Series<Number, Number>> data
        = chart.getData();

    data.add(waitingSeries);
    data.add(startedSeries);
    data.add(successSeries);
    data.add(failureSeries);

    pane.setCenter(chart);
}
```

OK, so:

- even though I set on *both axes* that the tick marks should not be visible, they are;
- even though I tell to the `xAxis` that its step should be 1, it shows fractions;
- and then there is this, where I update the data:

(work around bug with SO chat and bullet list vs code)

```
@Override
public void showLineMatcherStatus(final List<LineMatcherStatus> list,
    final int startLine, final int nrLines)
{
    display.xAxis.setLowerBound(startLine);
    display.xAxis.setUpperBound(startLine + nrLines - 1);
    // etc
```

`startLine` in this case is 1 and `nrLines` being 25, well, endLine is 25. Good, the bounds are respected...

... But then why does the x axis range from 0 to 27.5??

How do I make the axes behave?

Comment: Just a quick guess, don't have time to test, but you might need `xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);`

Comment: @James_D indeed, that fixes the x axis problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `NumberAxis` has `autoRanging` set to `true`, so to get it to respect your lower and upper bounds you need

```
xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
```

For the tick marks, if you look at your image closely, you'll notice there are no tick marks next to the actual numbers; only at the "minor values" in between.

So you need both

```
xAxis.setTickMarkVisible(false);
```

and

```
xAxis.setMinorTickVisible(false);
```

Comment: Yep, I found it afterwards, but thanks for the auto ranging hint!